# Тепловые карты накладываются друг на друга

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Здравствуйте!

Работаю с модулем тепловых карт от Яндекс.Карты. Есть страница с кнопками:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="studii" data-path="data/k0.json">студии</button>
    <button id="k1" data-path="data/k1.json">1к</button>
    <button id="k2" data-path="data/k2.json">2к</button>
    <button id="k3" data-path="data/k3.json">3к</button>
    <button id="k4" data-path="data/k4.json">4к</button>
    <button id="k5" data-path="data/k5.json">5к</button>
</div>
```

где при нажатии на кнопки, отображается соответствующая тепловая карта данным скриптом:

```
$('#studii, #k1, #k2, #k3, #k4, #k5').on('click', function() {
    path = this.getAttribute('data-path');
    jQuery.getJSON(path, function(json) {
        var heatmap = new ymaps.Heatmap(json['features'], {
            radius: 15,
            dissipating: false,
            opacity: 0.8,
            intensityOfMidpoint: 0.2,
            gradient: {
                0.1: 'rgba(128, 255, 0, 0.7)',
                0.2: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8)',
                0.7: 'rgba(234, 72, 58, 0.9)',
                1.0: 'rgba(162, 36, 25, 1)'
            }
        });
        heatmap.setMap(myMap);
    });
})
```

Затруднение в том, что тепловые карты накладываются друг на друга. А хотелось бы, чтобы предыдущая карта исчезала. Как это сделать?

Страница: http://yakhshisarova.ru/2/heatmap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаляйте старую тепловую карту с помощью `heatmap.setMap(null)`.

Comment: Не пойму, куда вставлять этот код. Думаю, сначала нужно проверить, есть ли тепловая карта на карте. Затем, если есть, уничтожить. Если нет - добавить. Как проверить наличие тепловой карты на карте?

Comment: Сохраните `heatmap` в глобальную переменную или замыкание. Перед созданием новой тепловой карты проверяйте есть ли старая. Если есть - удаляйте.